# Convert particular screen area into image in android

Tags: android

I have a question that I have an image which is shown on an activity with header text and footer text I want to join that header and footer in the image itself means image is changed with header and footer and then we want to send the same modified image as an email.

Please suggest me the right result regarding the same.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

**XML Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#ffffff">
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:background="@color/Red">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tv_Previrew_Header"
            android:text="Greeting" android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="18dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"></TextView>
    </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/btn_email"
            android:background="@drawable/email2x" android:layout_gravity="bottom"></Button>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/img_Preview_Image"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="270dip" android:layout_width="250dip"></ImageView>
        <TextView android:text="TextView" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tv_Preview_Greeting"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left" android:textColor="@color/Red" android:textSize="20dip" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_marginLeft="35dip" android:layout_marginTop="40dip"></TextView>
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/halosys_logo_bottom" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_gravity="right" android:layout_marginTop="320dip" android:layout_marginRight="40dip"></ImageView>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hey Paresh I didn't delete any question...........

Comment: how is your xml file ( means your view).

Comment: Please see my edited section.

Comment: What is the problem u r facing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert a view in to Bitmap

here the layout is your's required view

```
FrameLayout view = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.framelayout2);
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
view.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bm = view.getDrawingCache();
```